Text editor screen flickering after updating Ubuntu 22.04.1
A few days ago, I updated my Ubuntu 22.04.1 without paying much attention to the automatic update messages. Ever since then, I've been experiencing screen flickering issues with my NetBeans IDE 21. The problem seems to extend to other JetBrains CLion IDE and jEdit text editor as well, although other applications like Firefox are unaffected.
I've recorded the screen flickering, and you can check it out in this Google Drive *.mov file and this one. As for system details, my memory usage stands at 7.38GB out of 126GB, and I'm running Linux kernel version 6.5.0-28-generic.
I've searched online for solutions but haven't had any luck so far. If anyone could offer some assistance, I'd greatly appreciate it. Thanks in advance!
Edit:
Just found out this issue is more difficult than I thought: [REGRESSION] [535.54.03] The entire screen is frequently flickering #511 . So maybe this is not really relevant to NetBeans IDE. It is just somehow this issue is the most severe when I use NetBeans IDE 21.
